# Missing data in Section list view in Android?

Tags: android, android-listview

I am working with Section list view in Android to show Call details according to date.
Means under a particular date number of call details. But when I get 2 calls under the same date, the last date is visible only and the list does not show the rest of the calls of that date.

Calls under different dates are shown correctly but calls under same date are not shown correctly, only the last call is shown.

I am using the below code:

```
public String response = "{ \"Message\":\"Success\", "
        + "\"Data\":[ { \"ACCOUNT\":\"000014532497\", "
        + "\"DATE\":\"8/6/2006\", \"TIME\":\"15:37:14\", "
        + "\"CH_ITEM\":\"341T\", \"ITEM\":\"TIMEUSED\", "
        + "\"DESCRIPTION\":\"FROM3103475779\", \"DETAIL\":"
        + "\"UnitedKingdom011441980849463\", \"QUANTITY\":84, "
        + "\"RATE\":0.025, \"AMOUNT\":2.1, \"ACTUAL\":83.2, "
        + "\"NODE_NAME\":\"TNT02\", \"USER_NAME\":\"Shailesh Sharma\""
        + ", \"MODULE_NAME\":\"DEBIT\", \"ANI\":\"3103475779\", "
        + "\"DNIS\":\"3103210104\", \"ACCOUNT_GROUP\":\"WEBCC\", "
        + "\"SALES_REP\":\"sascha_d\", \"SALES_REP2\":\"\", \"SALES_REP3"
        + "\":\"\", \"IN_PORT\":\"I10\", \"EXTRA1\":\"RATE\", \"EXTRA2\":"
        + "\"44\", \"EXTRA3\":\"UnitedKingdom\", \"OUT_PORT\":\"I70\", "
        + "\"CRN\":\"WEBCC\", \"CallId\":null, \"ID\":4517734, \"PhoneNumber"
        + "\":\"011441980849463\" }, {\"ACCOUNT\":\"000014532497\",\"DATE\":"
        + "\"8/6/2006\",\"TIME\":\"09:22:57\",\"CH_ITEM\":\"541T\",\"ITEM\":"
        + "\"TIMEUSED\",\"DESCRIPTION\":\"FROM3103475779\",\"DETAIL\":"
        + "\"UnitedKingdom011447914422787\",\"QUANTITY\":1,\"RATE\":0.29,"
        + "\"AMOUNT\":0.29,\"ACTUAL\":0.5,\"NODE_NAME\":\"TNT02\",\"USER_NAME"
        + "\":\"Tusshar\",\"MODULE_NAME\":\"DEBIT\",\"ANI\":\"3103475779\",\"DNIS"
        + "\":\"6173950047\",\"ACCOUNT_GROUP\":\"WEBCC\",\"SALES_REP\":\"sascha_d"
        + "\",\"SALES_REP2\":\"\",\"SALES_REP3\":\"\",\"IN_PORT\":\"I30\",\"EXTRA1"
        + "\":\"RATE\",\"EXTRA2\":\"44\",\"EXTRA3\":\"UnitedKingdom-Special\","
        + "\"OUT_PORT\":\"I90\",\"CRN\":\"WEBCC\",\"CallId\":null,\"ID\":4535675,"
        + "\"PhoneNumber\":\"011447914422787\"}, ], \"NumberOfContacts\":2, "
        + "\"TotalCharges\":4.830000000000001 }";

try {
    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(response);
    String message = jsonObj.getString("Message");

    if (message != null && message.equalsIgnoreCase("Success")) {

        JSONArray dataArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("Data");
        System.out.println(dataArray.length());

        for (int i = 0; i < dataArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject history = dataArray.getJSONObject(i);
            _date = history.getString("DATE");

            String updatedDate = createDateFormat(_date);
            // notes =new ArrayList<String>();
            itemList = new ArrayList<Object>();

            // ADDING DATE IN THE ARRAYLIST<String>
            days.add(updatedDate);
            _username = history.getString("USER_NAME");
            _number = history.getString("PhoneNumber");
            _time = history.getString("TIME");
            _amount = history.getString("AMOUNT");
            _duration = history.getString("QUANTITY");

            /*
             * notes.add(_username); notes.add(_number);
             * notes.add(_time);
             */
            AddObjectToList(_username, _number, _time, _amount,
                    _duration);

            // listadapter = new <String>(this, R.layout.list_item,
            // notes);
            listadapter = new ListViewCustomAdapter(this, itemList);
            adapter.addSection(days.get(i), listadapter);
        }
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}

public class SeparatedListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    /*
     * public final Map<String, Adapter> sections = new
     * LinkedHashMap<String, Adapter>();
     */
    public final Map<String, Adapter> sections = new LinkedHashMap<String, Adapter>();
    public final ArrayAdapter<String> headers;
    public final static int TYPE_SECTION_HEADER = 0;

    public SeparatedListAdapter(Context context) {
        headers = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, R.layout.list_header);
    }

    public void addSection(String section, Adapter adapter) {
        this.headers.add(section);
        this.sections.put(section, adapter);
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        for (Object section : this.sections.keySet()) {
            Adapter adapter = sections.get(section);
            int size = adapter.getCount() + 1;

            // check if position inside this section
            if (position == 0)
                return section;
            if (position < size)
                return adapter.getItem(position - 1);

            // otherwise jump into next section
            position -= size;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        // total together all sections, plus one for each section header
        int total = 0;
        for (Adapter adapter : this.sections.values())
            total += adapter.getCount() + 1;
        return total;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        // assume that headers count as one, then total all sections
        int total = 1;
        for (Adapter adapter : this.sections.values())
            total += adapter.getViewTypeCount();
        return total;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        int type = 1;
        for (Object section : this.sections.keySet()) {
            Adapter adapter = sections.get(section);
            int size = adapter.getCount() + 1;

            // check if position inside this section
            if (position == 0)
                return TYPE_SECTION_HEADER;
            if (position < size)
                return type + adapter.getItemViewType(position - 1);

            // otherwise jump into next section
            position -= size;
            type += adapter.getViewTypeCount();
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public boolean areAllItemsSelectable() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
        return (getItemViewType(position) != TYPE_SECTION_HEADER);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        int sectionnum = 0;
        for (Object section : this.sections.keySet()) {
            Adapter adapter = sections.get(section);
            int size = adapter.getCount() + 1;

            // check if position inside this section
            if (position == 0)
                return headers.getView(sectionnum, convertView, parent);
            if (position < size)
                return adapter.getView(position - 1, convertView, parent);

            // otherwise jump into next section
            position -= size;
            sectionnum++;
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
}
```

This is my actual requirement:

[image]

This is what is happening right now.
[image]

Comment: can you post screenshot of current output?It will be helpful to grab the bug.

Comment: could you debug the code and check what is in the array of data before setting the value?

Comment: I have posted the current position image

Comment: post your layout xml file also

Comment: [here is two section listview](http://androidcustomviews.com/portfolio-category/custom-views/) check this.

Comment: I have already done with this.... Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SectionListExampleActivity is my Main class in which I am getting RESPONSE from JSON web service. In getJSONResposne method I am calling the **EntryAdaptor**.

There are two separate geter setter classes for SECTION HEADER and ITEM ENTRY for each header.

```
public class SectionListExampleActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener, OnItemSelectedListener, IServerResponse {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    private ArrayList<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
    boolean firstTime = true;

    private Spinner _spinner=null;
    private ArrayAdapter _amountAdaptor = null;
    private ArrayList<String> _monthList =new ArrayList<String>();
    private ListView _list=null;

    private Button _monthButton=null;
    private ImageButton _backImageButton=null;
    private ImageButton _headerImageButton=null;
    private String _token;
    private String _account;
    private Point p=null;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.account_history);

        String response = this.getIntent().getExtras().getString("history_resp");
        _token = Constant.AUTH_TOKEN;
        _account = Constant.ACCOUNT_NUM;

        _list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview);
        getJSON_Response(response,Constant.PID_ACCOUNT_HISTORY);

        EntryAdapter adapter = new EntryAdapter(this, items);

        _list.setAdapter(adapter);

        _monthList.add("Months");
        _monthList.add("January");
        _monthList.add("February");
        _monthList.add("March");
        _monthList.add("April");
        _monthList.add("May");
        _monthList.add("June");
        _monthList.add("July");
        _monthList.add("August");
        _monthList.add("September");
        _monthList.add("October");
        _monthList.add("November");
        _monthList.add("December");

        _spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.month_spinner);
        _amountAdaptor = new ArrayAdapter(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
                _monthList);
        _spinner.setAdapter(_amountAdaptor);
        _spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

        _monthButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.monthSpinner_button);
        _monthButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        _backImageButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.back_ImageButton);
        _backImageButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        _headerImageButton =(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.header_ImageButton);
        _headerImageButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    }


    private void getJSON_Response(String response,int pid) {

        switch (pid) {
        case Constant.PID_ACCOUNT_HISTORY:
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(response);
                String message = jsonObj.getString("Message");

                if(message!=null && message.equalsIgnoreCase("Success")){

                    JSONArray dataArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("Data");
                    System.out.println(dataArray.length());
                    String lastAddedDate = null;
                    for (int i = 0; i <dataArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject history = dataArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        String date  = history.getString("DATE");


                        if(firstTime || !(date.equalsIgnoreCase(lastAddedDate))){
                            firstTime=false;
                            lastAddedDate = date;
                            items.add(new SectionItem(date));
                        }
                        String username= history.getString("USER_NAME");
                        String number = history.getString("PhoneNumber");
                        String time = history.getString("TIME");
                        String amount=history.getString("AMOUNT");
                        String duration =history.getString("QUANTITY");

                        items.add(new EntryItem(username,duration,amount,number,time));
                    }
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(v==_monthButton){
            _spinner.performClick();
        }else if(v==_backImageButton){
            SectionListExampleActivity.this.finish();
        }else if(v== _headerImageButton){
            if (p != null)
                showPopup(SectionListExampleActivity.this, p);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position,
            long arg3) {
        if(position!=0){
            switch (parent.getId()) {
            case R.id.month_spinner:
                String selectedItem =  _spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
                _monthButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.month_blank);
                _monthButton.setText(selectedItem);

                final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
                String _historyURL = Constant.prodORdevUrl + "GetAccountHistory?token="+_token+"&account="+_account+"&month="+month+"&year="+year;
                getHistory(_historyURL,true);
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }           
}



public class EntryAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item> implements IServerResponse {

private Context context;
private ArrayList<Item> items;
private LayoutInflater vi;
private String _token;
private String _account;

public EntryAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<Item> items) {
    super(context,0, items);
    this.context = context;
    this.items = items;
    vi = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    _token = Constant.AUTH_TOKEN;
    _account = Constant.ACCOUNT_NUM;
}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;

    final Item i = items.get(position);
    if (i != null) {
        if(i.isSection()){
            SectionItem si = (SectionItem)i;
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_item_section, null);

            v.setOnClickListener(null);
            v.setOnLongClickListener(null);
            v.setLongClickable(false);

            final TextView sectionView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.list_item_section_text);
            String date  =createDateFormat(si.getTitle());
            sectionView.setText(date);
        }else{
            EntryItem ei = (EntryItem)i;
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_item_entry, null);
            final RelativeLayout relay = (RelativeLayout)v.findViewById(R.id.account_history_item_relay);
            final TextView username = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.user_name_textview);
            final TextView amount = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.amount_textview);
            final TextView duration = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.duration_textview);
            final TextView phone = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.phone_no_textview);
            final TextView time = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.time_textview);

            relay.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    makeCall(phone.getText().toString());
                }
            });

            if (username != null) 
                username.setText(ei.username);
            if(amount != null)
                amount.setText(ei.duration + "min");
            if(duration != null)
                duration.setText("$"+ ei.amount);
            if(phone != null)
                phone.setText(ei.number);
            if(time != null)
                time.setText(ei.time);
        }
    }
    return v;
}

void makeCall(String destination) {
    if(_token!=null && _account!=null){

        if(destination!=null && !destination.equals("")){
            String phoneNumber = Constant.getPhoneNumber(this.context.getApplicationContext());
            if(phoneNumber!=null && phoneNumber.length()>0){
                String callURL =WebService.WEB_SERVICE_URL+"PlaceLongDistanceCall?token="+_token +
                        "&phonenumber="+phoneNumber+"&destinationNumber="+destination+"&authtoken="+_token;

                getCall(callURL,true);
            }else{
                Constant.showToast(this.context, Constant.INSERT_SIM);
            }
        }else{
            Constant.showToast(this.context, "In valid destination number.");
        }
    }
}

}
```